# Nginx auth_basic prompting login on every request (Mobile browsers)

Tags: nginx, grafana

I am hosting an instance of Grafana, I have also configured my Nginx in order to ask for authentication request, it is working fine with web browsers, my problem is only with mobile browsers as it is asking login on every request almost every 3 sec.

I am getting this error with different mobile browsers

Below my Nginx configuration:

```
server {
  listen   3000;
  server_name localhost;
  auth_basic "Enter password!";
  auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/.htpasswd;

    location / {
    proxy_pass        http://grafana;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  }
    location /backup/ {
    proxy_pass http://flask/;
    proxy_read_timeout 600s;
  }
}
```